# How to use swift library in NativeScript?

Tags: ios, swift, nativescript

I am trying to use [this ios-charts library](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts) in NativeScript. This library is written in Swift and not in Objective-C. Can I use it? I have tried to use it but it is giving me an error. I have used it in following steps:

For which I have added library in my nativescript project using

```
tns library add ios 'library_path'
```

The library gets added. Then I prepared project for ios platform using

```
tns prepare ios
```

To test if library is added successfully, I build the project in `Xcode`, it builds successfully, but then I get the following error during runtime.

```
 dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
 Referenced from: /Users/UserNameHere/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Charts.framework/Charts
 Reason: image not found
```

I got rid of the this error when I set `Embedded content contains swift code` to `YES`. But now when I am trying to access the library as

```
var charts = new Charts();
```

It is giving a Reference error as below:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Charts
```

## What I have already tried:

I tried to access Charts using following methods:

```
1. var charts = new Charts.Swift();
2. var charts = new Charts.Charts();
3. var charts = new Charts-Swift();
4. var charts = new Charts.LineChartView();
5. var charts = require("Charts");
6. var charts = require("../../lib/Charts.framwork");
7. var charts = require("Charts.framework");
```

All these methods give the same exact error.

## References

I followed these links to develop my project

[Using-native-libraries-in-your-nativescript-apps](http://nuvious.com/Blog/2015/4/5/using-native-libraries-in-your-nativescript-apps)

Using native-libs with cocoa pods:  docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/native-libs/CocoaPods

Even if I try this with Cocoa Pods, it still gives the same error.

If anyone has tried this, please let me know.

Comment: It's not possible to use Swift third-party libraries at the moment. You can watch this issue regarding Swift support in NativeScript for iOS: https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime/issues/257

Comment: I successfully used this library, do you still need help?

Answer (score 10):

You can check for example my dialog plug-in:
https://github.com/enchev/nativescript-dialog

I'm consuming Swift library SDCAlertView and you can find more info about how to setup this in the pod and xconfig files:
https://github.com/enchev/nativescript-dialog/tree/master/platforms/ios

All classes most probably are avaialble in the global context. For example:

```
var chart = new BarChartView();
```